# How can I make hollow squares in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop

Okay so I need the output to print hollow squares and I'm at a loss right now. I don't want the answer but I would like some hints to help get me on the right track. Thanks!

```
"use strict"

if (process.argv.length < 3) {
    console.log("Not enough command-line arguments given.");
    console.log("Usage: node lab13_4.js num");
    process.exit();
}

var width = parseInt(process.argv[2]);



function makeLine(width) {
    var L = "";
    for(var w = 0; w < width; w += 1) { // repeated width many times
        L = L + ".";
    }
    return L;
}

// print the line some number of times.
function printLines(line, howMany) {
    // print the right number of lines
    for (var i = 0; i < howMany; i += 1) { // repeated height many times
        console.log(line);
    }
}

for (var x = 0; x <= width; x += 1) {
    var line = makeLine(x);

    printLines(line, x);
}
```

Comment: In your example, `process` is undefined. Could you please ensure you are providing **all** relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? :)

Comment: @ObsidianAge: Perfectly defined in Node.

Comment: How this work is I would type "node lab13_4.js" to the console except I would add a number so like this "node lab13_4.js 5" and the number 5 would be put into process.

Comment: So apparently my question got flagged for something. I'm new to this website and to coding. Could someone please explain what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If LENGTH be the length of the sides of the square.
You have to make nested loop and check boundary conditions.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < LENGTH; j++) {
    if (i == 0 || i == LENGTH - 1 || j == 0 || j == LENGTH - 1) {
      process.stdout.write("*")
    } else {
      process.stdout.write(" ")
    }
  }
  process.stdout.write("\n")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We are looking for a solution like this:

```
*****
*   *
*   *
*   *
*****
```

The top and bottom sides of the square have the full amount of stars.
All lines in between will only have one star in the beginning of the line and one star at the end of the line.

I use the following function:

```
function square(input) {
    // top line
    console.log('*'.repeat(input));
    // middle lines
    for(let i = 1; i < input - 1; i++) {
        console.log('*' + ' '.repeat(input-2) + '*');
    }
    // bottom line
    console.log('*'.repeat(input));
};

square(5);
```

hope this makes sense :)